# Почему не выдает результат?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import randint
B = []
A = [randint (0,30001)
    for x in range (1001)]
M = 0
i = 1
if A[i]>10 :
    while A[i]>10:
        M = A[i]%10
print(M)
```

Comment: У вас бесконечный цикл

Comment: старайтесь более информативные заголовки использовать [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на эти строки:

```
while A[i]>10:
    M = A[i]%10
```

A[i] всегда больше нуля, т.к. Вы не меняете значение A[i], поэтому у Вас получается бесконечный цикл (из-за этого и не выдает результат).
Насколько я понял, Вы хотели написать вот это:

```
from random import  randint
B = []
A = [randint (0,30001)
    for x in range (1001)]
M = 0
i = 1
if A[i]>10 :
    while A[i]>10:
        A[i] %= 10
        M = A[i]
print(M)
```